# Keras Input add dimension autoly error

Tags: keras

I am a new hand of using Keras. After searching without results. Please Please save me!
Here is my problem:

```
print(input_shape)

X_input = Input(input_shape)

print(X_input)
```

result in

```
(600, 64, 64, 3)
Tensor("input_5:0", shape=(?, 600, 64, 64, 3), dtype=float32)
```

It add one dimension autoly and error

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv0: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that in `keras` a first dimension is connected to a number of samples (I guess it's 600 in your case) and it's skipped while defining an input `shape`. So try:

```
X_input = Input(input_shape[1:])
```

in order to skip a sample dimension.

Comment: @yeafun, if you consider this answers your question, please mark it as answered :)